# How do I make std::getline inform me when it has hit the end of a stringstream?

Tags: c++, io, stringstream

Supposing stringstream contains `James is 4` , I can write something like `getline (stream, stringjames, ' ')` to get the individual words, but is there any way to know that I've hit the end of the line?

Bonus Question!
Case 1: `James is 4`
Case 2: `James is four`

If I were iterating through the words in a stringstream, and I expect to receive an int val of 4, but instead I received a string, what would be the best way to check this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You check the return value to see if it evaluates true or false:

```
if (getline(stream, stringjames, ' '))
    // do stuff
else
    // fail
```

As for the "bonus question" you can also do the same thing when extracting `int`s and things from streams. The return value of `operator>>` will evaluate to `true` if the read was successful, and `false` if there was an error (such as there being letters instead of numbers):

```
int intval;

if (stream >> intval)
    // int read, process
else if (stream.eof())
    // end-of-stream reached
else
    // int failed to read but there is still stuff left in the stream
```

Comment: +1, that is what I would do, although to precisely answer the question, you should not only test whether the stream is valid, but also that the failure is due to reaching end-of-file (and not any other error)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas thanks, I amended the answer to reflect that. I don't think you need to do that with `getline` though since it won't fail for any other reason (I think).

Answer (score 1):

> Supposing stringstream contains James is 4 , I can write something like getline (stream, stringjames, ' ') to get the individual words, but is there any way to know that I've hit the end of the line?

It's normally easiest to read into  a `std::string` variable - the default is to consider it delimited by space anyway:

```
std::string word;
while (some_stream >> word)
{
    // first iteration "James", then "is", then "4", then breaks from while...
}
```

> Bonus Question! Case 1: James is 4 Case 2: James is four
>
> If I were iterating through the words in a stringstream, and I expect to receive an int val of 4, but instead I received a string, what would be the best way to check this?

You're best off reading it into a `string` first, then checking whether you can convert that `string` into a number.  You might try `strtoi` `strtol` etc. - they helpfully indicate whether the entire value is a legal number so you can detect and reject values like say "4q".

An alternative is to try streaming into an integral type first, and only if it fails reset the error flags on the stream and get a string instead.  I can't remember if you could need to reposition the stream so you could read the string variable, but you could write a couple test cases and nut it out.

Alternatively, you could use regular expressions and subexpression matches to parse your input: more useful as the expression gets more complicated.